# [DockPanel-Suite]How do I make my window appear in the lower right corner programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, docking, dockpanel-suite

This is a question about how to use dockpanel-suite. As you know, when a form is loaded first time, we can choose the dockstyle through setting the property ShowHint. Now I want a dock effect neither DockRight nor DockBottom, I want an effect "DockRightBottom" when the form is loaded for the *first* time. Now I can get this effect through a mannal drag and drop operation after the form is loaded.

[image]

As shown in the above picture, the properties window in the visual studio is docked in the lower right corner. How can I make my window shown in this *Right Bottom* position programmatically.
Thanks a lot for all your instructions.

Comment: There's [no such thing](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=showhint&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4#refinementChanges=117&pageNumber=1&showMore=false) as a `ShowHint` property on a WinForms form.  What toolkit are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. I forgot sth important just now. Actually this is a question about how to use the open source component dockpanel-suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to have panels shown side by side you can follow this article,

http://docs.dockpanelsuite.com/en/latest/tutorials/basics.html

The below code is modified a little bit to dock them on the right side,

```
dmcDownloadMonitor.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockRight);
amcActivateModsMonitor.Show(dmcDownloadMonitor.Pane, DockAlignment.Bottom, 0.5);
```

You can see that we moved all documentation to this new site

http://docs.dockpanelsuite.com

So spare some time on it to see if there is anything else useful.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your code

```
Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
        this.Location = new Point(workingArea.Right - Size.Width,
                                  workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height);
```

It loads your application to the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly instruction. Sorry, I have edited the question. I forgot sth important just now. Actually this is a question about how to use the open source component dockpanel-suite.